# Field Test using Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, signals, signal-strength

Apple just removed the possibility to show the signal strength in dBm on the iPhone.
Does anyone know a possibility to get the signal strength programmatically via Swift for iOS 11? I really need this for an app which I am programming on.
This will be just an internal app and nothing to publish in the AppStore.

Comment: @Adrian did you actually check that repo before linking it? It clearly is only a `UIView` sublclass for displaying values, but has nothing to do with actually measuring signal strength.